# Show only files which name starts with a specific letter

Tags: grep, ls

My task is to output a list of files with there attributes which names starts with `'p'` letter using `ls` and `grep`.

I am using `ls -Rl` to show list of files, like this, but I don't have an idea how to output only `'p'` letter files:

```
ls -lR | grep -v :$ | grep -v total | grep -v "^$"
```

Comment: Throwing your question out here and copying the answers you're given teaches you nothing. It would be far better for you to demonstrate what you have tried so far and to ask for help with anything specific that eludes you (especially if your course leader notices their task posted here).

Comment: `ls -Rl` will list both files and directories

Comment: Well I got only this so far `ls -lR | grep -v :$ | grep -v total | grep -v "^$"`

Comment: Please update question with amendments.

Comment: You should be able to do this with just `ls` and a shell (such as bash). No need for `grep`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, probably this homework assignment is written by someone who doesn't fully grasp the use of file globs, so they've come up with this task to try to teach about `grep` even though it's the wrong tool for *this* job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of code:

```
 ls -Rl | awk '/^-/ && $NF ~/^p/'
```

Prints the file list only if it satisfies the below two conditions.

- `/^-/` line starts with a hyphen.
- `$NF ~ /^p/` last column starts with p. ( only if we don't have space in the filename)

I would prefer to use `find` command rather than parsing `ls`

```
find . -type f -name "p*" -ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something important in your question, I'd say that you can accomplish this simply via [file globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229465/what-is-file-globbing):

```
ls -l p*
```

This command lists files and directories beginning with `p`. No need to use `grep`.

Comment: Simplest and easiest to remember, will solve for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

As OP stated using grep and show the attributes. With GNU grep:

```
ls -Rlp | grep -v / | grep -P "(?<=:[0-9]{2}[[:blank:]])p.*"
```

Comment: this would print directories as well

Comment: Edited the answer